# Binding ComboBox ItemsSource and SelectedItem to different DataContexts

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

In my application, I have an object `MaterialLibrary` that holds a list of various materials names, and an object `UserInputData` that holds various user inputs. `MaterialLibrary` and `UserInputData` are and should be completely separate objects.

The intent is that a `ComboBox` is populated from property `MaterialLibrary.MaterialNames` (`ObservableCollection<string>`), and whatever material user chooses, is written to `UserInputData.SelectedMaterialName` (`string` with `NotifyPropertyChanged` implemented).

The first part implies that the `DataContext` of the `Page` that hosts this `ComboBox` should have it's DataContext set like this:

```
public partial class MaterialSelectionPage : Page
{
    public MaterialSelectionPage(MaterialLibrary matLib)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = matLib;
    }
}
```

And the ComboBox should be defined like this:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="MaterialSelectionComboBox" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MaterialNames}"/>
```

However, the second part implies that `DataContext` should be set like this:

```
public partial class MaterialSelectionPage : Page
{
    public MaterialSelectionPage(UserInputData inputData)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = inputData;
    }
}
```

And the definition of `ComboBox` therefore should be:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="MaterialSelectionComboBox" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedMaterialName}"/>
```

These two requirements are clearly clashing together, as the `MaterialSelectionPage` and by extension `ComboBox` can only have one `DataContext`. I don't see any easy way of using a single model in this example, because `MaterialLibrary` and `UserInputData` need to be completely separate objects, and there is no sense in having a reference of one inside the other.

Can anyone suggest what is the correct way to implement this intent?

Comment: You don't have to change the DataContext, if one Binding should resolve a Path from a data source other than the DataContext. A `Binding` in XAML has at least four different ways of resolving its data source. 1. use the DataContext provided. 2. explicitly define a Binding.`Source` (that is a different object than the DataContext) 3. explicitly define Binding.`RelativeSource` 4. refer to an UI Element nearby with Binding.`ElementName` .
It's up to you which one you prefer.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.binding?view=windowsdesktop-7.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a single class-wrapper, which will contain instances of `MaterialLibrary` and `UserInputData` as properties. Then provide that wrapper to the View and set as DataContext.

For example:

```cs
public class MultipleDataContextWrapper
{
    public MaterialLibrary MatLibInstance { get; }
    public UserInputData InputDataInstance { get; }

    public MultipleDataContextWrapper()
    {
        // Initialize instances in some way
    }
}
```

Then provide that wrapper to the View:

```cs
public partial class MaterialSelectionPage : Page
{
    public MaterialSelectionPage(MultipleDataContextWrapper dataContextWrapper)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = dataContextWrapper;
    }
}
```

And in XAML access the properties of the wrapped instances as subproperties of the wrapper properties:

```xml
<ComboBox x:Name="MaterialSelectionComboBox" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MatLibInstance.MaterialNames}"
          SelectedItem="{Binding Path=InputDataInstance.SelectedMaterialName}"/>
```

Comment: I was considering this, but is this really the way to go? It adds another layer in the application hierarchy making it inconsistent with other parts that reference UserInputData or MaterialLibrary directly (like in my example). Or perhaps that is of no concern?

Comment: It is for you to decide, is it applicable for your purposes/project architecture etc. or not. I think wrapper isn't layer, it looks like a "shortcut" to the instances, but it doesn't supposed to recreate that instances or modify them in some way. Just a "reference holder"

Comment: Appreciate the explanation. Okay, I will do it this way.